# Invariance of dimension

Tags: general-topology

What does "invariance of dimension under continuous bijective map mean"? This came up in somewhere associated with Brouwer's Theorem (but not sure).

And only thing near it I can remember is there can be no continuiuous bijection from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ $m\neq n$. But these seem to contradictory(??).

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is a result from the invariance, not a contradiction. If you have a continuous  bijection $f:X\rightarrow Y$ you know that the dimension of your image $f(X)$ is the same as the dimension of $X$, so dimension $X$ = dimension $Y$.